# How to check if it is the first time a user has used my app

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I am wondering what the best method is to check if it is the first time a certain user has used my app, and also when they update will it reset and make it think they are a new user.

Edit(For more precision): I want to store a user id number in my sql server, and I want every user to create a password when they first download, but I also want them to have the option to select "Already have account" so that they can sync their accounts across devices

Comment: I would think having them register an account would suffice. Then just store a flag once they've met your, 'first time using this app' requirements. Too vague of a question honestly..

Comment: I have changed the post to hopefully be more specific

Comment: I think your own update already answers the question.

Comment: I understand the logic I want to use but should I use sharedpreferences or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Illegal Argument mentions, the most reliable way is to use a server, because if you use a Shared preference, the user can delete the data or move to a different device and appear to be a totally new user.

If you don't want to go through the trouble of creating and managing your own server, you might consider using [Google's Cloud Save API](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/cloudsave).  When your app starts, check for existing data in the cloud.  If there's nothing there it's a new user so create the data.  It should be as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way to know that the user is a first time user is via a server validation. Another way to do it would be to use shared preference and saving certain data in internal or external storage. However storing data in mobile is not so foolproof as data can be easily deleted by user.

Answer (score 0):

**Globals**

```
String _StrCode="";
SharedPreferences preferences;
String _responseCode=null;
```

**In oncreate but before set content view check**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    preferences = getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0);        
    _StrCode= preferences.getString("Code", _StrCode);
            if(_StrCode.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_qdc_status__launcher);
                  // here you can assign a value to 
                      _StrCode ="some value";
                      Editor prefsEditor = preferences .edit();
          prefsEditor.putString("Code",_StrCode);
                      prefsEditor.commit();
             }else{
                 Intent _in= new Intent(firstscreen,secondscreen.class);
         startActivity(_in);
           finish();
             }
}
```

i hope this will halp you and its easy to understand too.